# Updating current posts in production's targetable_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, production-environment

I have two tables, one of which I changed to have polymorphic associations. I have a production environment with about 40 posts, and I want to change their `targetable_id` and `targetable_types`, but I'm having trouble through the CL with:

```
Design.first.update_attributes(targetable_id: 1, targetable_type: "Collection")
-->false
```

In this case, the former way to find the design was with a `collection_id`, and now that's changed to a `targetable_id`. The Collection ID on this specific design is `1`.

How can I do this without deleting all the posts and starting over?

Comment: can you try Design.first.targetable = Collection.find(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `update_columns` which will update the database directly without performing any callbacks or validation:

`Design.first.update_columns(targetable_id: 1, targetable_type: "Collection")`

However, if it were me, I'd try to figure out exactly why it's failing...  If you try:

`Design.first.update_attributes!(targetable_id: 1, targetable_type: "Collection")`

... the console should give you additional information as to why it's failing, which may help you run `update_attributes`.

Comment: Is there a way to do that but update multiple at once like Design.find(14) through 40???

Comment: Sure, you could put this in an iterator...  `Design.where(:id => 14..40).each {|design| design.update_columns( ... ) }`